# When are immediate materialized views updated

Tags: sql, materialized-views, sqlanywhere

I use SQL Anywhere 11.

I have the following view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "DBA"."PointsAcc"( /* view_column_name, ... */ )
IN "SYSTEM" AS
select sum(PL.Points) AS Sum, DP.UserUID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Points DP
KEY JOIN PointLine PL
KEY JOIN PointHead PH
GROUP BY DP.UserUID
```

I have a trigger in PointLine that should select the sum from this view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "WorkOnPoints" AFTER INSERT, DELETE
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."Points"
REFERENCING OLD AS oldrow NEW AS newrow 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare @points integer;
    set @points = (isnull((select isnull(Sum, 0)) FROM PointsAcc where UserUID = newrow.UserUID), 0)) 
END;
```

The @points variable now contains the sum from before the line was inserted or deleted. How can i get the updated sum from the view in the trigger?

Comment: The solution is a statementlevel trigger. SQL Anywhere uses row leval triggers to update the view and "user" triggers are run befor this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Version of SQLA you have currently use.

If you did not create the View with immediate refresh option you have to call

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view-list
```

For more details check out these Links

http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/alter-materialized-view-statement.html

And

http://dcx.sybase.com/1201/en/dbreference/refresh-materialized-view-statement.html